# WSO2CEP:Selecting Event Receiver Type

Tags: logging, virtual-machine, host, event-receiver, wso2-cep

I am using `WSO2CEP` as processing tool over logs generated from `bro`. These logs are in `json` format and resides on a virtual machine (`guest`). My `WSO2CEP` is on `host` machine. 
As it supports various event adapters for communicating events to server:

1. Email Event Receiver
2. File-tail Event Receiver
3. HTTP Event Receiver
4. JMS Event Receiver
5. Kafka Event Receiver
6. MQTT Event Receiver
7. SOAP Event Receiver
8. WebSocket Event Receiver
9. WebSocket Local Event Receiver
10. WSO2Event Event Receiver

I am looking for the best selection where I could push events from `guest` to `host`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use wso2 event receivers which uses thrift as the protocol. It delivers better performance results and it can be further tuned. Please refer performance tuning recommendations [1] if you want to further optimize throughput and latency.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Performance+Tuning+Recommendations#PerformanceTuningRecommendations-CEP-LevelsettingsEventConfiguration

Comment: Sorry I didn't distinguish diff of `wso2cep` and `wso2das`. Actually I have no DAS and only running CEP on host machine while logs exist on guest. As far as I think I should write a simple java service to use http event receiver and send data to host. Would it be good?

Comment: I thought there are two instances, i have updated the answer. Yes you can write a java thrift publisher and publish your log to cep. You can refer our sample producer client code for wso2event. https://github.com/wso2/product-cep/blob/master/modules/samples/producers/wso2-event/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/sample/wso2event/Client.java

Comment: Thankyou so much but my guest is unable to access host at url https://172.30.13.95:9443/carbon considering 172.30.13.95 is ip address of my host. It says `The webpage at https://172.30.13.95:9443/carbon/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`

Comment: If it can be accessed in local machine. It seems like a network issue when accessing from guest, make sure that 9443 port is open in firewalls. Apart from that thrift uses 7611 port to communicate